# How can i do smooth scrolling in fluid iframe facebook application?

Tags: facebook, scroll, smoothing, fluid

I have this button:

```
<a href="#" id="toTop" style="display: inline; ">Top</a>
```

I'd like to know if is possible to do something like this jquery code does, inside facebook application iframe:

```
$('#toTop').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });​
```

Thanks ;)!

**EDIT 1 (Following Matthew Johnston Answer):**

This is what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ajXjg/4/

*NOTE:* [FB.Canvas.scrollTo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/) doesn't work with fluid canvas setting

**EDIT 2 (For someone who need [i hope for now]):**

The only way is to use anchor link, you don't get smooth scroll :(...and in firefox they don't work!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this works, I just set it up and it failed to happen. You do have the Facebook Javascript SDK method [FB.Canvas.scrollTo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/) which will allow you to scroll to specific locations in an canvas app, however it won't be smooth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry fo that, i edit my question to add JSFiddle link to see what i mean. FB.Canvas.scrollTo doesn't work with fluid canvas setting :(, and i need it. There's another way? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you have any Javascript way of getting this to work, because of the Same Origin Policy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which will disallow JS in an iFrame from interacting with a parent frame that is from a different domain. I think your only option is to use anchor links.

Comment: Thanks. Now i'm using anchors and all work well..but i can't control animations and other effects. I think this is a limit of facebook application, that force developers to don't use the best (or more beautiful) solution.Do you think that there will be a solution someday? I hope...